# Workaround for named range Search function issue in Excel

Tags: excel, search, range, named

I have a bank export of Credit card vendors. As these vary, I use unique strings contained in each to identify them. For example here is a lookup table excerpt. 
[First Lookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8iAl.png)

I then apply a formula `=INDEX(First_level,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Keywords,C3374)),0))` to produce this:
[First calc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9mqH.png)
I found this formula here https://exceljet.net/formula/get-first-match-cell-contains

Then I reapply the formula to the result ie the `First_Level` using this formula `=INDEX(Second_Level,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Frst_Lev_Check,H44)),0))` with this Lookup. 
[Second Lookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wdrb.png)

Most of the time it works, but for this I get the following
[Second calc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwvHx.png), where the first level classification is correct, but the second level one is completely wrong.

When I've gone into the depths of the formula, the issue is that the Search function is returning the wrong value.

This appears to be a known issue:  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-use-named-range-in-search-function/14c8c989-bed0-48f9-bce0-c0894571b557

Ideas welcome on workarounds/how to solve the problem.

Cheers Jon

Answer (score 1):

Would you consider:

```
=MATCH("Apple",List)
```

and

```
=MATCH("Pear",List)
```

to return `1` and `2` respectively.

Comment: Thanks @pnuts - have a headache - will have another go tomorrow.

Comment: Head clearer now @pnuts - don't think this works - I need a range - have explained better above. Cheers Jon

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things in regards to your question:

1. The correct syntax for `search` is `=SEARCH(find_text,within_text)`, so the correct formula would be `=SEARCH("Pear",List)`.
2. The reason why you are getting the `#Value` is, because you are applying `search` to a range, but the function is only intended for cells.
3. The best ways to see if a value exists in a range are the `countif` and `match` function:

The `countif` function shows you **how many times the a value is in a range**:

[image]

The `match` function shows you **in which row the the first value is**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @VBAPete - that's what I thought originally. I've been basing it on this https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-one-of-many-things, which seems to work. 

What I'm doing is this (it's a spreadsheet to take the Credit card download from the bank and process it via two levels into categories I can use through matching names). This is the formula it's in - https://exceljet.net/formula/get-first-match-cell-contains.

Have a headache today - will try your ideas tomorrow. Cheers Jon

Comment: Are looking for a word match in a cell with s string?

Comment: Yes. I have a bank export of Credit card vendors. As these vary, I use unique strings to identify them eg. `Amazon` for `AMAZON UK AMAZON.CO.U LUX FRGN AMT: 22.97`. I want to assign a value to all cells with this like `Online purchase` using a lookup table. I've been using this formula `=INDEX(First_level,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Keywords,C4270)),0))` where `C4270` is the exported value, `Keywords` is the column I have `Amazon` in and `First_level` is the column I have `Online purchase` in. Then I reapply this to group them again. Works once but not on the second time. Cheers Jon

Comment: You have `AMAZON UK AMAZON.CO.U LUX FRGN AMT: 22.97` in `online purchases` and `Amazon` in `keywords`, which you would like to match against the `amazon` in your  `online purchases` string. What do you want returned when it matched?

Comment: thanks for your help - completely rewritten as I realised how hard it was to follow - hope it makes it clearer. Cheers Jon

Comment: Does only the second level calculation not work? That should be a straight forward `index/match`.

Comment: And what is the first level for `transport`?

Comment: I haven't explained that well - I take the cell, check against `Keywords` and the Index/match/search function returns `First_Level`. I then take the `First_Level` result and run it through the same function (with a different lookup table) to produce the `Second_Level` result. I have noticed the issue in the `Second_Level` for `Transport`, but it is possible it occurs in the first level. 

When I used `Evaluate Formula` on the problem, `Index` and `Match` appeared to be working, but the `Search` component returned the wrong value. This was an `8` ie the string started at the 8th character. ??

Comment: The three `First_Level` values in the `Lookup` table for `Transport` are `PTV`, `Car` and `BICYCLE NETWORK`